# Camunda: Remove Business Key prompt from user-initiated Process?

Tags: camunda

We are introducing the Camunda Tasklist UI to our business users and they have requested not to be prompted to enter a Business Key when a user initiates a Process. Is this possible?

Currently the flow is: Click Start Process > Select Process from available options > **Prompt for Business Key value** > First task initiated.

It's this prompt we're looking to remove.

Comment: Hi, @rob2universe. I don't yet have the reputation to upvote, but I've accepted the answer. The further research into this is on our dev team's backlog. Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the properties of the start event you can find the 'forms' tab. If you define one or more form fields in the 'Form Fields' section, the start process UI will be replaces with a UI including only the field you have specified.

The auto generated form is the simplest approach to replace the generic UI. However, you can also use a custom form, either your own HTML or a form using the new from builder, described here: https://camunda.com/blog/2021/04/camunda-forms-visual-editing-of-user-task-forms/
You can try it here: https://bpmn.io/toolkit/form-js/

Related documentation: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/user-guide/task-forms/